# Q:How do i get assisted conversion by metrics in Google Analytics Reporting API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I wanna get metrics of assisted conversion with dimension=ga:sourceMedium,
but couldn't find the param in the official exlorer sites

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/

Anyone know this metrics tha can use with the dimension above?

for now, i use this params to get data and make reports

```
metrics=ga:goalCompletionsAll, ga:internalPromotionClicks,ga:organicSearche
dimension=ga:sourceMedium
```

Answer (score 2):

Assisted conversions are part of [Multi-Channel Funnels Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/reference). There's a dedicated [list of available metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/dimsmets) and dimensions for these types of reports and data. E.g source / medium as `mcf:sourceMedium`